# Excel VBA if condition being executed after not being met

Tags: vba, excel

I am having some troubles with an IF statement in my code, I noticed the code was not doing what it was meant to, and it is due to a buggy IF statement.

The code below checks if two values match, these two values are **targetcolumnvalue** and **sourcecolumnvalue**.  If these two values match, excel will perform a copy/paste based on cell row and column positions using these values as the column and row identifiers.

When I debugged the code, the targetcolumnvalue was equal to 26, and the sourcecolumn value was equal to "", but the code was executing on the scenario that the if statement was being met.  Am I not seeing something here?

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit

Sub BuggyIf()

    Dim SourceColumnValue As String, sourcerow As String, targetrow As String, targetcolumnvalue As String, sourcecolumnnumber As String
    Dim F as long, O As Long, P As Long, TargetValue As Long, actualsourcerow As Long, actualtargetrow As Long, actualtargetcolumn As Long, sourcedateposition As Long, actualsourcecolumn As Long, targetdateposition As Long, actualtargetforecastrow As Long
    Dim Copysource As Range, pastetarget As Range

    TargetValue = dumpsheet.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    sourcedateposition = dumpsheet.Cells(rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row
    targetdateposition = dumpsheet.Cells(rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).row

    For F = 1 To sourcedateposition
        SourceColumnValue = dumpsheet.Cells(F, 5).Value
        'Get Target Column Match to Source
        For P = 1 To targetdateposition
            targetcolumnvalue = dumpsheet.Cells(P, 7).Value

            ' BUGGY IF STATEMENT
            If targetcolumnvalue = SourceColumnValue Then
                TargetColumnRange.Value = SourceColumnValue
                targetcolumnvalue = dumpsheet.Cells(P, 8).Value
                sourcecolumnnumber = dumpsheet.Cells(F, 6).Value

                For O = 1 To dumpsheet.Cells(rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).row
                    If O > 1 Then
                        Sourcename = dumpsheet.Cells(O, 1).Value
                        sourcerow = dumpsheet.Cells(O, 2).Value
                        targetrow = dumpsheet.Cells(O, 3).Value
                        dailyrate = dumpsheet.Cells(O, 4).Value

                        'Set Integers
                        actualsourcerow = CInt(sourcerow)
                        actualtargetrow = CInt(targetrow)
                        actualtargetcolumn = CInt(targetcolumnvalue)
                        actualsourcecolumn = CInt(sourcecolumnnumber)
                        actualtargetforecastrow = actualtargetrow - 521
                        dailyfte = CInt(dailyrate)

                        'Copy and Paste
                        Set Copysource = SourceSheet.Cells(actualsourcerow, actualsourcecolumn)
                        Set pastetarget = TargetSheet.Cells(actualtargetrow, actualtargetcolumn)

                        If pastetarget.Cells.Interior.Color <> 1 Then

                            Copysource.Copy
                            pastetarget.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

                            Set Copysource = TargetSheet.Cells(actualtargetrow, actualtargetcolumn)
                            Set pastetarget = TargetSheet.Cells(actualtargetforecastrow, actualtargetcolumn)

                            Copysource.Copy
                            pastetarget.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

                            fte = TargetSheet.Cells(actualtargetforecastrow, actualtargetcolumn).Value / dailyfte
                                            TargetSheet.Cells(actualtargetforecastrow, actualtargetcolumn).Value = fte

                        End If
                    End If
                Next O
            End If
        Next P
    Next F
    ....
End Sub
```

Comment: please add a validation(condition) if not targetvalue =""  or sourcevalue ="" then add your if condition inside.

Comment: I am running this now as we speak, is there an explanation as to why an if statement by itself would run whilst the condition isn't being met in VBA?

Comment: The reason is sourcecolumn is holding null value. Null can be also equated to 0 which again is part of long datatype. Either you source column should not have null (can use - as an alternative) or you need to handle the Null validation.

Comment: Strange, I just ran your code, the sourcecolumnvalue returned "" but the code is still running?

Comment: Please revisit the condition is IF NOT. Also, can you check manually if the sourcecolumn has empty space without values. In that case, you need to use trim.

Comment: Restarted my computer and it fixed it, seems the compiler wasn't behaving.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting my computer fixed this, seemed like VBA wasn't compiling properly.